# ASP.NET 5 : Is the "dotnet" command replacing "dnu" and "dnx" commands?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux

Today, I was following multiple tutorial to run a C# application on Linux but always got stuck at the command `dnu restore` which was returning me a `not found` error. Later on, I found out [this page](http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/) which seems to indicate that the new command is `dotnet restore` and when I tried it, it worked.

Are the `dnu` and `dnx` commands completely replaced?

Also, is there some documentation somewhere about the `dotnet` commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the `dotnet` command replacing `dnu` and `dnx` commands?

Yes. They are introducing new command line toolchain, [ASP.NET 5 will transition to the new tools for RC2. This is already in progress. There will be a smooth transition from DNX to these new .NET Core components.](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/intro-to-cli.md)

> Are the `dnu` and `dnx` commands completely replaced?

No. You can use `dnu` and `dnx`, if you follow this instruction [Installing .NET Core on Linux](http://dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/installing/installing-core-linux.html).

> Is there some documentation somewhere about the dotnet commands?

[CLI Repo](https://github.com/dotnet/cli) / [Intro to .NET Core CLI - v1.0.0](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/intro-to-cli.md)

Comment: You say that `dotnet` is going to replace `dnu` and `dnx`, yet you say at the same time that they are not going to be replaced completely. Why? To my understanding, `dotnet` offers everything that `dnu` does and is also multiplatform, so why should the `dnu` tool be kept alive? With `dnx` it may be different because that's execution environment tool, not development tool. But `dnu` feels completely obsolete to me now.

Comment: @VojtěchVít I use the `dnu` command to add packages to a particular project. I don't see anything in the `dotnet` command for package management except for restore.

Comment: @VojtěchVít: It looks like they are planning dotnet-install-package, after that I couldn't see a real need for dnu. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/76

Answer (score 1):

Here the basic things

**1** `dnu restore` & `dnx run` works for version `1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x64` (check using `dnvm list`) and `project.json` file needs minimum

```
"compilationOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true
},
"frameworks":{
    "dnxcore50":{
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Console":"4.0.0-*"
        }
    }     
}
```

**2** `dotnet restore` & `dotnet run` works for version `1.0.0-rc2-23811` and project.json file needs minimum

```
"compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
},
"dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
}
```

Along with this need `NuGet.config` file.

Now, based on How `project.json` file configured and `dnvm` **active** set, you need to use command.