# Are the dotnet utilities (dnu) retired? What replaces the global commands?

Tags: python-sphinx, chocolatey, dnu, .net-core, docfx

[Following the `sphinx-autoapi` integration with `docfx` guide](https://github.com/rtfd/sphinx-autoapi#id1), they suggest installing `docfx` using the following command:

#### Install DocFX using DNU (*deprecated ?*)

```bsh
dnu commands install docfx
```

Did **DNU** get retired - I just ended up using **chocolatey**, but it seems like global commands have been dropped in .NET Core CLI. Hoping someone can confirm [what happened to **.NET Utilities**](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155264/what-are-dnx-dnvm-dnu-and-other-aspnet-5-components).

#### Install DocFX using Chocolatey

```bsh
choco install docfx
```

Comment: You know, you could always ask them - https://github.com/dotnet and https://github.com/dotnet/docfx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dnvm repository](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm#readme) says it's obsolete, but the [dotnet repository](https://github.com/dotnet/cli) isn't really providing a command translation. This [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/migrating-from-dnx) on migrating says there's no equivalent `dotnet install` command.

> **Installing dependencies**
>
> As of v1, the .NET Core CLI tools don't have an install command for installing dependencies. In order to install a package from NuGet, you would need to add it as a dependency to your project.json file and then run dotnet restore.

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198295/3619) confirms that it's obsolete/replaced, but that dnu/dnx *can* still be used.

Comment: Thanks @Anthony Mastrean - the [recommended install for DocFX seems to be chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/docfx) which they [automatically target for releases](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx). The `sphinx-autoapi` docs is out of date.